# Setting up ArcPy SQL Query that allow for "one" or "both" selection

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, sql, definition-query, arcgis-10.8

I am writing a code that will query two attributes, zoom to layer and output a map. The problem I am having is in some cases the user will likely only want to query one of the two attributes.

How can I code this to allow for both instances?

In some instances the user will want to select the entire tract, while in others they will want to chose a field number specific to that tract.

```py
import arcpy, os

#################### ASSIGN VARIABLES ###########################

Tract = ("111")
CLU = ("2")

#################################################################
     
# Select a tract using the TRACNBR attribute and zoom to selected
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'LandUnits', df)[0]
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION",  'TRACTNBR IN ({0}) AND CLUNBR IN ({1})'.format(Tract, CLU))
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
lyr.definitionQuery = 'TRACTNBR IN ({0})AND CLUNBR IN ({1})'.format(Tract, CLU)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Any ideas how I can set up this query?

Comment: Are you receiving input from the user at the start of the script? To create the variables Tract? CLU? You could also ask them, "Will you be querying Tract, CLU, or both?" Then based on their input, you set up the query.

Comment: It's just an `if` block to change the WHERE clause, no?  Your code doesn't seem to attempt a solution, or indicate how the values will change.

Comment: @timlohnes Im setting this up to distribute. There are a few other folks in my work who would like the whole code that this pertains to for map making. So Im trying to set it up so they just have to input the variables in the "Assign Variable" block.

Comment: @vince Im not a coder by any stretch. I'm a conservationist who makes a lot of maps for work. Im not really sure how to set up and If block for this clause. I dont really know how to even attempt a solution. I have tried to look it up, but didnt know what to look up exactly. The values are basically numbers assigned to fields. Im using this code to all the user to select a field and output maps for conservation.

Comment: You can make a toolbox to give to other users. They click on a tool and it asks them the questions you need. They don't have to do anything in code. The tool opens a popup that asks them What tract number are you querying (leave blank for none)? Then, What CLU are you querying (leave blank for none). Does your code work the way you want now. Looks like that is  a query for both Tract and CLU? Zooms to features, only shows the desired features.

Comment: Im working on the toolbox now ( have other problems with that, but that's another question). The tract number is specific to each land parcel. CLU numbers or field numbers are generic (i.e. Every Tract has a fld 1). the problem I am running into is that if the CLU is left blank it returns the error "ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute). " In some instances, my users will want to make maps for the whole tract, in others, they will need it for specific fields within the tract

Comment: @timlohnes I have certain constrictions so i might not be able to distribute a tool in that regard, but ill be able to send the code to people and walk them through it

Comment: Got it. That works too. Ok. So take your queries above and alter they need to be edited for 2 cases (Tract with CLU, Tract without CLU). Is that right?

Comment: @timlohnes exactly! So that they can put their input in " Tract = ### AND CLU = # " or just "Tract = ###"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. If CLU is empty (""), then only query Tract. Else, query both.

```
if CLU == "":
  arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION",  'TRACTNBR IN ({0}) '.format(Tract))
  df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
  lyr.definitionQuery = 'TRACTNBR IN ({0})'.format(Tract)
else:
  arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION",  'TRACTNBR IN ({0}) AND CLUNBR IN ({1})'.format(Tract, CLU))
  df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
  lyr.definitionQuery = 'TRACTNBR IN ({0})AND CLUNBR IN ({1})'.format(Tract, CLU)
```

Comment: that worked perfect! thank you. I am slowly learning and this will be banked away for future use!

Comment: Glad to hear it!